# Infinite descending membership sequence not equivalent to axiom of foundation in ZF

Tags: set-theory

The axiom of foundation in ZFC, which states that every non-empty set $S$ has an element $s$ which is disjoint from $S$, implies that there is no infinite descending membership sequence. I was told that the converse can be proven by assuming the axiom of choice. That raises the question, is there a model of ZF such that there is no infinite descending membership sequence, but the axiom of foundation does not hold?

Comment: Presumably you mean ZF *without foundation*?

Comment: Just a wild guess, perhaps we can take inspiration from the permutation models. Taking a sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ of "atoms", except with the relations $x_{i+1} \in x_i$, and then constructing a permutation model as we would do to have an amorphous set. Of course it doesn't make quite sense, because we don't have non-trivial automorphisms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I mean ZF without foundation.

Comment: I had mentioned it before in comments. Of course this use of DC is necessary.